# to drag and drop the entire content from one div to all other div in back forth manner

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do the same but not able to do so. Actually I have created five div and I want the entire information contained in one div to drag and drop in all other div in back and forth manner.
Here is my code:
JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <div id="box" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">hey !! this is me ....</div>

    <div id="box" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">Draggable item 1 </div>

    <div id="box" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">Draggable item 2 </div>
    </div>

    <br>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div><br>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div><br>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div><br>
```

Comment: please read this article and try that and update the answer with where you stuck. 
https://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/mastering-drag-and-drop-with-jquery-ui.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got your code working like this https://jsfiddle.net/50ar7wpk/11/

```
<head>
  <style>
    .container {
      background-color: #DDD;
      height: 80px;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 4px;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function allowDrop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
      ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
      ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container" class="container" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <div id="box1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">hey !! this is me ....</div>
    <div id="box2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Draggable item 1 </div>
    <div id="box3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Draggable item 2 </div>
  </div>

  <br>
  <div id="div1" class="container" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="div2" class="container" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="div3" class="container" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</body>
```